# Blend 2013 looks weird

Tags: forms, xaml, expression-blend, blend

It the first time im trying to design xaml with Blend so i really have no idea if it is something wrong with my project of if there is a problem with Blend.

This is what my Blend looks like:

[image]

And on the youtube clips that im trying to follow their Blend looks like this:
[image]

There seemst to be missing a lot of stuff on the left side menu in my Blend!
But why?

Thanks!

Comment: When I had problems like this (only xaml view available, no design view) it was because of .Net version in the project http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/expression-blend-4-cannot-seeswitch-to-design-view/. I don't know if this is a similar problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so as for your first part, hit your "Windows" menu item at the top and enable your other windows like your States, Parts, Objects & Timeline (Which on yours looks like it says "Live DOM" or something which is more or less accurate to its purpose), etc.

The second part, it looks like you're missing your designer view. Tap <kbd>F11</kbd> until you get what you want, it will toggle you through designer only, code only, or split view. Or you can hit the corresponding buttons for this on the top right of stage window.

Some of your other stuff will be dependent on what you're interacting with and will toggle the visibility of what's available accordingly. Like if you have a Resource Dictionary actively open, your Assets won't be select-able until you drill into an actual Style template or something.

Once you get the hang of it, you'll come to love blend for numerous things depending on how much of a designer you are. Just please for the love of anything holy, don't become accustomed to just dragging/dropping and not learning the XAML, you'll end up with bloated and ugly code in many cases and become dependent on the properties screen. It's the only down side to it.

Eventually most folks get to the point they just use blend for things like storyboarding or vector asset creation and the likes, the designer type stuff it was really made for where its real strengths lie.

Anyhow, hope this helps, cheers!